# Saving an array of objects in localStorage

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I'm trying to add an item to localStorage array to make an array of objects and iterate it somewhere in my Angular 2 app. This is how I'm trying to save my localStorage item:

```
if (!this.search_history) {
    localStorage.setItem('search_history', JSON.stringify(this.calc));
}
else {
    localStorage.setItem('search_history', this.search_history + ',' + JSON.stringify(this.calc));
}
```

And in the component where I'm trying to iterate:

```
private searchHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('search_history')) || [];
```

I go really confused about how it supposed to work, I think I have problem with the way I was trying to insert a new array item. Not sure if I can use push in this case.

What's the proper syntax to insert a new array record?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code: `...'search_history', this.search_history + ',' + JSON...`?

Comment: I need to replace this line with the right syntax to insert a new item to my array

Comment: Type of Object.

Comment: So it is defined as `calc: Object;`?

Comment: `private calc = {max:0, min:0};`

Comment: Most likely what you want to do is stringify the array for local storage, then retrieve it, parse it, push the new item, re-stringify, and then re-store. What does `this.search_history` contain?

Comment: this.search_history is the `private search_history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('search_history')) || [];` When I try to `push I get: `this.search_history.push is not a function`